Is there any way to determine distance of ejected electron from cathode surface in thermionic emission?
I was reading on the topic of work function on wikipedia and it says that the emitted electron is at a distance of 'many nanometers' from the surface of the metal. I was wondering if there has been any research done on this topic that gives a range of distances electron may be found at after emission from a particular metal say tungsten?
Is there an expression that can help me estimate the ejection distance. I want to calculate the force on the ejected electron by the image charge left on the surface. To do that I need distance of emitted electron from the surface. Is there any other way I can approach this problem?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function
My main reason for asking this question is to determine whether or not the electron would be recaptured by the surface just after it has been emitted. I was doing some reading on vacuum tubes and there they use thermionic emission and present a theory of space charge. In the absence of anode voltage like in a light bulb what happens do these emitted electrons. Even in vacuum tubes what does the balance of forces look like on electrons. That is the attractive force from anode and from image charge left behind on the cathode. If the electrons are too close to the surface the cathode electric fields should dominate over anode fields and recapture the electron .
Can you point me in the right direction to resolve these questions?

The Wikipedia article describes measurement techniques. It seems that should point you in the right direction?

With enough energy it is a free electron heading off into infinity…

Thanks. The measurement techniques in the wikipedia article are for measuring the WF of the material. I want to know the distance of ejected electrons when WF requirements are met. The goal is to calculate the resultant force by the image charge left behind on the surface after electron has been ejected. For that I need distance to which it travels after ejection. I'm unable to find a a solution to this....

@JonCuster I might be wrong,please correct me if so, but from what I understand the increased energy leads to a release of more electrons (richardson law in thermionic and fowler nordheim in field emission)and don't necessarily lead to increase in velocity of emitted electron. Hence the accumulation of space charge around the filament.
